# My app in Review almost for 20 hours is it good?

Tags: iphone, ipad

the previous app had been took just 2 hours ?

Comment: It might even take couple of days.. dont worry. Apple guys take their own time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience application review usually takes about 1-2 weeks. That's improved a bit lately but 2 hours and even 20 hours sounds way too fast for Apple. So do not worry - all you can do now is just wait...

Answer (score 0):

Be patient and wait and see

Answer (score 0):

20 hours is not a long time for Apple. The time taken in review depends mainly on the size of the app. It may take more than one week if it has many features. And yes, 2 hours seems too fast.